# code in ocr how I can take text from image

Tags: c#

How can I take a text from image I have code in ocr but is not run it's broken in the line
    modiDocument.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH);

it is all the code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string filePath = ("image\an91cut.jpg");
        string extractText = this.ExtractTextFromImage(filePath);
        label1.Text = extractText;

    }

    private string ExtractTextFromImage(string filePath)
    {
        Document modiDocument = new Document();

         modiDocument.Create("C:\\Users\\אפרת\\Desktop\\oo.png");
        modiDocument.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH);
        MODI.Image modiImage = (modiDocument.Images[0] as MODI.Image);
        string extractedText = modiImage.Layout.Text;
        modiDocument.Close();
        return extractedText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of option for OCR but I think you shouldn't use MODI, I can suggest Tesseract OCR  [here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) .